# Revoke CREATE for a user from Google Cloud SQL Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, users, google-cloud-sql

I'm using Google Cloud SQL Postgres and having difficulty revoking privileges to create tables from a user.

I first removed all roles and attributes from the user (truncated for brevity):

```
mydatabase=> \du+
                                                             List of roles
         Role name         |                         Attributes                         |           Member of            | Description
---------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+-------------
 cloudsqlsuperuser         | Create role, Create DB                                     | {pg_monitor,pg_signal_backend} |
 myuser                    |                                                            | {}                             |
 postgres                  | Create role, Create DB                                     | {cloudsqlsuperuser}            |
```

This worked for preventing the user from accessing data in existing tables, but the user was still able to create new tables. I figured this might be because of the default `CREATE` privilege `PUBLIC` has to the `public` schema so I tried revoking both that and any specific privileges for the user...

```
postgres=> REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE
postgres=> REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE "mydatabase" FROM "myuser";
REVOKE
postgres=> REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM myuser;
REVOKE
```

But the user still has access to `CREATE` tables within `mydatabase`:

```
mydatabase=> SELECT pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege('myuser', 'public', 'CREATE');
 has_schema_privilege
----------------------
 t
(1 row)
```

I thought maybe the issue was that the permissions were at the database level and not the schema level so I tried revoking them there as well, but no luck:

```
postgres=> GRANT ALL ON DATABASE "mydatabase" TO cloudsqlsuperuser;
GRANT
postgres=> GRANT ALL ON DATABASE "mydatabase" TO postgres;
GRANT
postgres=> REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE "mydatabase" FROM myuser;
REVOKE
postgres=> REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE "mydatabase" FROM public;
REVOKE
postgres=> GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE "mydatabase" TO myuser;
GRANT
```

The output of `\dn+` doesn't show any other permissions that should affect this user AFAIK:

```
postgres=> \dn+
                                       List of schemas
  Name  |       Owner       |           Access privileges            |      Description
--------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+------------------------
 public | cloudsqlsuperuser | cloudsqlsuperuser=UC/cloudsqlsuperuser+| standard public schema
        |                   | =U/cloudsqlsuperuser                  +|
        |                   | postgres=C/cloudsqlsuperuser           |
(1 row)
```

Additionally, the `search_path` is default:

```
postgres=> SHOW search_path;
   search_path
-----------------
 "$user", public
(1 row)
```

How do I correctly remove the `CREATE` privilege for this user?

Comment: Please show the result of `\dn+` and the setting of `search_path`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I edited the question and added those details, thanks

Comment: Thanks. That should be possible if all connections are to the same database. But perhaps Google has modified PostgreSQL permissions.

Comment: @ashgromnies this is way too late but did you ever figure out a solution for this?

Comment: @AkashAgarwal yes, IIRC I had to revoke the default `public` group permissions: `REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;` as well